# Web.config not deployed to bin folder on OOTB WCF Web Service Application Project

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have a standard WFC web service application, and when I build it, the web.config file does not get copied to the output bin directory. I've just tried creating a brand new WcfService1 project, building it with no changes from the template, and the same thing is happening. Any ideas on what the cause could be? Visual Studio 2012 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore me, I'm being an idiot. Web.config isn't supposed to end up in the bin folder.